# Why would you want to insert into a table to be uploaded to the actual table later?

Tags: sql-server

When looking through a database, I found tables that seem to only exist to hold data before a bulk insert into the main version of the table.  For example, for a table `Location` there would be a table `Location_upload`.  The tables appear to be identical aside from the `_upload` version containing a `processed` bit column.  Apparently, the data is added to the `_upload` table and then a bulk job will load things into the actual table.  I believe this job is hourly.

When I asked why it was done this way, it pretty much boiled down to someone that no longer works here thought it should be that way.  The only reasons I could think of are:

1) In the event something goes wrong, you have a record of what was trying to be inserted.

This doesn't make much sense since the insert into the `_upload` table would have to work.  If that works, why not just insert directly into the main table?

2) Some kind of data manipulation is done that goes faster in bulk or makes it seem faster for the user.

Also doesn't seems to hold up since the tables appear to be the same aside from a single bit column.  Even looking up rows that went through the process seems to give the same data values.

What other reasons could there be for wanting to have this waiting room style table structure?  Is this a common practice anywhere else?

Comment: We use staging tables here so that if the insertions failed for whatever reason, the data still exists and can be corrected to try the insertion later, mostly EDI processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do quite a bit of data integration.  Staging tables are fairly common for bulk imports with what I work with.

I use them in one system because I import data from an external system that doesn't know all the necessary information.  I need to populate a column in the staging table before it can be inserted into the actual table, and that column is a NOT NULL column in the actual table.  I could do this with SSIS, but a) I didn't know SSIS that well at the time I wrote it, and b) it works very fast with pure SQL, and c) as you say, it leaves a record of what data got imported.

In another system, the data from three different data files is imported into three different staging tables.  However, the data from these files needs to be transformed into records for about 15 different live tables, including some entity-attribute-value tables that are quite complex.  I have 15 different VIEWs defined which generate the records from the 3 source staging tables as well as half a dozen tables already in the database, and then I execute MERGE statements to update the live tables.

Now, you *could* do this with temp tables, but if you need it every day (or every hour) and keeping the table around actually helps, a regular table works very well.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common ETL pattern. Allows for the data to accumulate at a slower pace (insert), it then it can be modified to fit the business rules, and finally inserted into the real data. This allows for shorter blocking (only while the final bulk insert), it prevents data from becoming visible while being verified and transformed. This pattern usually is called [staging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data)).